# Build JSON object directory tree using Python os.walk

Tags: python, json, os.walk

So I'm just hitting a mental roadblock on solving this problem and none of the other questions I have looked at have really captured my particular use-case. One was close but I couldn't quite figure out how to tailor it specifically. Basically, I have a script that uses `os.walk()` and renames any files within a target directory (and any sub-directories) according to user-defined rules. The specific problem is that I am trying to log the results of the operation in JSON format with an output like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-12-26 09:40:55.874718",
    "files_inspected": 512,
    "files_renamed": 256,
    "replacement_rules": {
        "%20": "_",
        " ": "_"
    },
    "target_path": "/home/example-user/example-folder",
    "data": [
        {
            "directory": "/home/example-user/example-folder",
            "files": [
                {
                    "original_name": "file 1.txt",
                    "new_name": "file_1.txt"
                },
                {
                    "original_name": "file 2.txt",
                    "new_name": "file_2.txt"
                },
                {
                    "original_name": "file 3.txt",
                    "new_name": "file_3.txt"
                }
            ],
            "children": [
                {
                    "directory": "/home/example-user/example-folder/sub-folder",
                    "files": [
                        {
                            "original_name": "file 1.txt",
                            "new_name": "file_1.txt"
                        },
                        {
                            "original_name": "file 2.txt",
                            "new_name": "file_2.txt"
                        },
                        {
                            "original_name": "file 3.txt",
                            "new_name": "file_3.txt"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The first item in the 3-tuple (`dirpath`) begins as the target directory, and on that same loop the second item in the 3-tuple (`dirnames`) is a list of the directories within that `dirpath` (if any). However, what I think is messing me up is that on the second loop, `dirpath` becomes the first item in `dirnames` in the prior loop (if there were any). I am having trouble working out the logic of transforming this 3-tuple loop data into the nested hierarchy above. Ideally, it would be nice if a directory object which had no sub-directories (`children`) would also not have the `children` key at all, but having it set to an empty list would be fine.

I would really appreciate any advice or insight you might have on how to achieve that desired log structure from what `os.walk()` provides. Also open to any suggestions on improving the JSON object structure. Thank you!

https://github.com/dblinkhorn/file_renamer

Comment: It would be a lot easier if instead of providing a list of children you had a _dict_ of children keyed by file or directory names; that way you can directly index your way down the structure without needing to do potentially-expensive O(n) searches. Which is to say -- this isn't a well-designed documented format if one of the goals is efficient search for (or updates within) a given subtree. Is the layout an external constraint?

Comment: Really appreciate that tip and explanation. I'll implement that change.

Comment: The structure seems fine to me, depending on what you want to do with it. But I don't see any code here.

Comment: Sorry, I linked to my GitHub repo which has the current script code, but the logic to construct this JSON object programmatically is just what I have been unable to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue in your approach is that you want a hierarchical result that is most naturally obtained by recursion, whereas `os.walk` flattens that hierarchy.

For this reason, I would recommend using [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) instead. It also happens to be one of the most performant tools to interact with a directory tree.

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

def rename(topdir, rules, result=None, verbose=False, dryrun=False):
    is_toplevel = result is None
    if is_toplevel:
        result = dict(
            timestamp=datetime.now().isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='microseconds'),
            dryrun=dryrun,
            directories_inspected=0,
            files_inspected=0,
            files_renamed=0,
            replacement_rules=rules,
            target_path=topdir,
        )
    files = []
    children = []
    with os.scandir(topdir) as it:
        for entry in it:
            if entry.is_dir():
                children.append(rename(entry.path, rules, result, verbose, dryrun))
            else:
                result['files_inspected'] += 1
                for old, new in rules.items():
                    if old in entry.name:
                        newname = entry.name.replace(old, new)
                        dst = os.path.join(topdir, newname)
                        if not dryrun:
                            os.rename(entry.path, dst)
                            result['files_renamed'] += 1
                        if verbose:
                            print(f'{"[DRY-RUN] " if dryrun else ""}rename {entry.path!r} to {dst!r}')
                        files.append(dict(original_name=entry.name, new_name=newname))
                        break
    result['directories_inspected'] += 1
    res = dict(directory=topdir)
    if files:
        res.update(dict(files=files))
    if children:
        res.update(dict(children=children))
    if is_toplevel:
        res = result | res
    return res
```

#### Example

Let's build a **reproducible example**:

```py
d = {
    'example/example-folder': [
        'file 1.txt',
        'file 2.txt',
        'foo bar 1.txt',
        {
            'sub/folder': [
                'file 1.txt',
                'file 2.txt',
                'foo bar 1.txt',
            ],
        },
    ],
}

def make_example(d, topdir='.'):
    if isinstance(d, str):
        print(f'make file: {topdir}/{d}')
        with open(os.path.join(topdir, d), 'w') as f:
            pass
    elif isinstance(d, dict):
        for dirname, specs in d.items():
            topdir = os.path.join(topdir, dirname)
            print(f'makedirs {topdir}')
            os.makedirs(topdir, exist_ok=True)
            make_example(specs, topdir)
    else:
        assert isinstance(d, list), f'got a weird spec: {d!r}'
        for specs in d:
            make_example(specs, topdir)

>>> make_example(d)
makedirs ./example/example-folder
make file: ./example/example-folder/file 1.txt
make file: ./example/example-folder/file 2.txt
make file: ./example/example-folder/foo bar 1.txt
makedirs ./example/example-folder/sub/folder
make file: ./example/example-folder/sub/folder/file 1.txt
make file: ./example/example-folder/sub/folder/file 2.txt
make file: ./example/example-folder/sub/folder/foo bar 1.txt
```

```bash
! tree example
example
└── example-folder
    ├── file\ 1.txt
    ├── file\ 2.txt
    ├── foo\ bar\ 1.txt
    └── sub
        └── folder
            ├── file\ 1.txt
            ├── file\ 2.txt
            └── foo\ bar\ 1.txt

3 directories, 6 files
```

Now, using the `rename()` function above:

```py
rules = {'%20': '_', ' ': '_'}
res = rename('example', rules, verbose=True, dryrun=True)
# [DRY-RUN] rename 'example/example-folder/file 2.txt' to 'example/example-folder/file_2.txt'
# [DRY-RUN] rename 'example/example-folder/file 1.txt' to 'example/example-folder/file_1.txt'
# [DRY-RUN] rename 'example/example-folder/sub/folder/file 2.txt' to 'example/example-folder/sub/folder/file_2.txt'
# [DRY-RUN] rename 'example/example-folder/sub/folder/file 1.txt' to 'example/example-folder/sub/folder/file_1.txt'
# [DRY-RUN] rename 'example/example-folder/sub/folder/foo bar 1.txt' to 'example/example-folder/sub/folder/foo_bar_1.txt'
# [DRY-RUN] rename 'example/example-folder/foo bar 1.txt' to 'example/example-folder/foo_bar_1.txt'

>>> print(json.dumps(res, indent=4))
{
    "timestamp": "2022-12-29 15:24:06.930252",
    "dryrun": true,
    "directories_inspected": 4,
    "files_inspected": 6,
    "files_renamed": 0,
    "replacement_rules": {
        "%20": "_",
        " ": "_"
    },
    "target_path": "example",
    "directory": "example",
    "children": [
        {
            "directory": "example/example-folder",
            "files": [
                {
                    "original_name": "file 2.txt",
                    "new_name": "file_2.txt"
                },
                {
                    "original_name": "file 1.txt",
                    "new_name": "file_1.txt"
                },
                {
                    "original_name": "foo bar 1.txt",
                    "new_name": "foo_bar_1.txt"
                }
            ],
            "children": [
                {
                    "directory": "example/example-folder/sub",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "directory": "example/example-folder/sub/folder",
                            "files": [
                                {
                                    "original_name": "file 2.txt",
                                    "new_name": "file_2.txt"
                                },
                                {
                                    "original_name": "file 1.txt",
                                    "new_name": "file_1.txt"
                                },
                                {
                                    "original_name": "foo bar 1.txt",
                                    "new_name": "foo_bar_1.txt"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is working beautifully. I suspected it would require a recursive solution given that a directory can have n children, but still couldn't quite wrap my head around the logic to implement it. Thank you for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure if I got your request right. But to get a simple nested structure from `os.walk` you could try the following:

```
import json
import os
from typing import Union

structure = {}

def get_element(dirpath: str) -> Union[dict, None]:
    _element = structure[root]
    if dirpath.startswith(root):
        dirpath = dirpath[len(root)+1:]
    for key in dirpath.split(os.sep):
        try:
            _element = _element[key]
        except KeyError:
            return None
    return _element

target = os.path.abspath('sample')
root, _ = target.rsplit(os.sep, 1)
structure[root] = {}
for path, children, files in os.walk(target):
    element = get_element(path)
    if element is None:
        element = structure[root][path.split(os.sep)[-1]] = {}
    element['files'] = files
    for child in children:
        element[child] = {}

print(json.dumps(structure, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

yields an output like

```
{
    "/path/to/folder": {
        "sample": {
            "dir": {
                "files": [
                    "more_samples.txt"
                ],
                "subdir": {
                    "files": [
                        "important.txt"
                    ]
                },
                "with": {
                    "children": {
                        "files": [
                            "other.txt",
                            "some.txt"
                        ]
                    },
                    "files": []
                }
            },
            "files": [
                "test.txt"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Does this help?

---

Note: this is a minimal example, trying to solve the main part of the request.
You need to build the rest of your structure around it.

---

Note 2: The key `files` might cause a conflict if you have a subfolder names `files` somewhere. Choose wisely. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! When i tested this logic it appears that it creates each subdir object, but does not actually place the subdir data into that object, but instead creates a new root-level object for each subdir.

Comment: Shoot. I did not realize that you are working with absolute paths. Updated answer acordingly.